# How to describe a thorough researcher?

Tags: word-choice

How to describe a researcher who works thoroughly, digs deep, and nothing escapes his notice. What is(are) the best word(s) to describe him/her in addition to thorough: sharp, subtle, or something else?

Comment: **Passionate**?

Comment: There are any number of words you could use depending on what you want to emphasise and what the context is.  The first word that came to my mind was **excellent**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me, the word that comes to mind is:

> **diligent**
>
> having or showing care and conscientiousness in one's work or duties.
>
> "after diligent searching, he found a parcel"

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was looking for. BTW, do "sharp" and "subtle" sound natural? I'm in doubt about that.

Comment: "Subtle" doesn't sound quite right; it generally means "difficult to see or understand". To describe a researcher as subtle, I would imagine him perhaps gathering information in such a way that other people aren't aware he's doing it. If a researcher was described as "sharp", I would imagine them as intelligent, quick, capable of picking up on subtleties/discrepancies, etc. (as an analogy, a sharper blade is more effective than a dull one, as with a pencil, etc.).